# XPath, return default value if node is empty

Tags: php, xpath

I have a very simple scraping PHP script that uses XPath to scrape the data into an HTML table that i can then put into an excel file.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$arr = array("http://website1.com",
             "http://website2.com",
  );

echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach ($arr as &$value) {

$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. $value;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//dd/span");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($elements as $element) {

    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo "<td>".$node->nodeValue. "</td>\n";
    }

  }
  echo "</tr>";
}

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Now, some of the pages that I am scraping have empty span values, this is causing my HTML tables to lose their structure as the script is not creating an empty table cell for the empty  elements.

Is there a way that I could add in the ability to print a default value such as "N/A" whenever the  element is empty?

Thanks

Comment: What is *have empty values*? *Pages* have empty values? Please [edit] your question and be more clear.

Comment: You can inspect $node->nodeValue in your foreach. That's a simple if statement.

Comment: @Jan Doggen  I think that's what you mean :)  `echo "<td>".($node->nodeValue === '' ? 'N/A' : $node->nodeValue). "</td>\n";`

Comment: @user2637655 I already wrote the code

Comment: Sorry, I meant the span tags that i'm scraping can sometime have empty values. @splash58, thanks, i gave that a try but it still just prints the table without those cells

Comment: @user2637655  put var_dump ($node->nodeValue) and look what is when cell is empty. does it falls in foreach?

Comment: @splash58 there is not any nodeValue showing at all for a span element that is empty when i do var_dump, seems that is why nothing is being printed with Jan's code